# Surprisingly bad c# switch performance

Tags: c#, performance, switch-statement

I have created a `TypeSwitch` class to cast my fields using a code similar to the following shortened sample:

```
static Dictionary<Type, int> TypeDefs = new Dictionary<Type, int>() 
{
    {typeof(Int16), 1},
    {typeof(Int32), 2},
    {typeof(Int64), 3},
    {typeof(IntPtr), 4},
    ...
    {typeof(String), 18}
};

public static object ConvertFromDBValue(Type type, object value) 
{
    try 
    {
        switch (TypeDefs[type]) 
        {
            case 1: // {typeof(Int16), 1},
            {
                return Convert.ToInt16(value);
            }
            case 2: // {typeof(Int32), 2},
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
            case 3: // {typeof(Int64), 3},
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64(value);
            }
            ...
            ...
            ...
            case 17: // {typeof(Char), 17},
            case 18: // {typeof(String), 18},
            {
                return value.ToString().Trim();
            }
            default: 
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Using instrumentation tool, I see over 60% of the time is spent in the function body of the above `ConvertFromDBValue`, i.e. I spend more time because of switch (or try-catch) than look up the Type value in `Dictionary.get_Item` and converting the value (e.g. `Convert.ToInt32`). Actually, I spend 3 times more time in the function body than the `Dictionary.get_Item`...

This is somehow surprising to me - can anyone confirm the `switch` is so much slower, or is there any other reason for this?!

**UPDATE**
I removed the try-catch part but this didn't really much...

Comment: I doubt it's `switch` that slows you down. I suspect it is the boxing of the value which takes time. If your dictionary is strongly typed then it would work very fast.

Comment: switch is fast as it should. it depends. how many times you call this method? don't use try-catch over and over because that is way slow.

Comment: BTW: (Not related with your performance issue) A dictionary like `Dictionary<Type, Func<object,object>>` can be a neater solution which eliminates the use of *switch* ....     **`Dictionary<Type, Func<object,object>> TypeDefs = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> () {
                {typeof(Int16), x=> Convert.ToInt16(x) },
                {typeof(String), x=> x.ToString().Trim() }

            };

            var val = TypeDefs[typeof(short)]("12345");`**

Comment: @L.B Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Well there is something faster than a switch if you want to try speeding that up -- but boxing and unboxing it notoriously slow.  You can make an array of functions and array index to pick the convert function instead of using a switch.

Comment: @Hogan Is there a suggested alternative?

Comment: I guess so since I suggested it.

Comment: I meant for the boxing part....

Comment: There is no way to get around the boxing part if you are going to store all types in a single value.  Multiple values (and memory) for the types will avoid the boxing and unboxing.

Comment: @Hogan we are moving off-topic with boxing. I'll ask a new question about it. Thanks for your answer on switch though!

Comment: What is the dictionary for? Why can't you just compare type directly?

Comment: @mayu Because c# doesn't have a "Type" switch...!

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned you are paying the boxing/unboxing penalty and if possible you should try to eliminate it.

As for the body of the method you should get rid of the dictionary and use a chain of if `if elses` - it should give you a measurable improvement in performance.

---

EDIT

After Hogan's comment I've tested it and to my surprise the difference between *dict+catch* vs *if* is less was between 5%-15% (*if* was slightly faster) in my imperfect test below.

```
Dict+case: 987.0945ms
Ifs: 937.5104ms
Hogan's array of funcs: 854.4887ms
```

Test:

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<Type, int> TypeDefs = new Dictionary<Type, int>()
    {
        {typeof(Int16), 1},
        {typeof(Int32), 2},
        {typeof(Int64), 3},
        {typeof(IntPtr), 4},
        {typeof(char), 5},
        {typeof(String), 6}
    };

    static KeyValuePair<Type,object>[] _Types = new[] 
        { new KeyValuePair<Type,object> ( typeof(Int16),5 ),
        new KeyValuePair<Type,object> (typeof(Int32),57 ),
        new KeyValuePair<Type,object> (typeof(Int64),157 ),
        new KeyValuePair<Type,object> (typeof(IntPtr),new IntPtr(6) ),
        new KeyValuePair<Type,object> (typeof(String),"Hello!" ),
    };

    public static object ConvertFromDBValue(Type type, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (TypeDefs[type])
            {
                case 1: // {typeof(Int16), 1},
                    {
                        return Convert.ToInt16(value);
                    }
                case 2: // {typeof(Int32), 2},
                    {
                        return Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    }
                case 3: // {typeof(Int64), 3},
                    {
                        return Convert.ToInt64(value);
                    }
                case 4: // {typeof(IntPtr), 4},
                    {
                        return value;
                    }
                case 5: // {typeof(Char), 17},
                case 6: // {typeof(String), 18},
                    {
                        return value;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        return value;
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static object ConvertFromDBValue2(Type type, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (type == typeof(Int16))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt16(value);
            }
            if (type == typeof(Int32))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
            if (type == typeof(Int64))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64(value);
            }
            if (type == typeof(IntPtr))
            {
                return (IntPtr)value;
            }
            if (type == typeof(Char) || type == typeof(String))
            {
                return value.ToString().Trim();
            }
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    static Func<object, object>[] funcList =
    {
        (value) => value,                    //0
        (value) => Convert.ToInt16(value),   //1
        (value) => Convert.ToInt32(value),   //2
        (value) => Convert.ToInt64(value),   //3
        (value) => value,   //4
        (value) => value,   //5
        (value) => value,   //6
        (value) => value,   //7
        (value) => value,   //8
        (value) => value,   //9
        (value) => value,   //10
        (value) => value,   //11
        (value) => value,   //12
        (value) => value,   //13
        (value) => value,   //14
        (value) => value,   //15
        (value) => value,   //16
        (value) => value,   //17
        (value) => value.ToString().Trim() //18
    };

    public static object ConvertFromDBValueHogan(Type type, object value)
    {
    return funcList[TypeDefs[type]](value);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        Random random = new Random(113453113);


        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var x = random.Next(5);
            var testValue = _Types[x];
            var p = ConvertFromDBValue(testValue.Key, testValue.Value);
        }
        var elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine($"Dict+case: {elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var x = random.Next(5);
            var testValue = _Types[x];
            var p2 = ConvertFromDBValue2(testValue.Key, testValue.Value);
        }
        elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine($"Ifs: {elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var x = random.Next(5);
            var testValue = _Types[x];
            var p3 = ConvertFromDBValueHogan(testValue.Key, testValue.Value);
        }
        elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine($"Hogan's array of funcs: {elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that - I get the point - `if-else` is slower for items at the end of the list, but still faster as dictionary access... As for boxing, I opened a new question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812841/improve-efficiency-of-database-row-reading-without-boxing)...

Comment: This is wrong a dictionary should be faster than chained if-else and switch -- unless you know something about frequency.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some sample code if my "array of functions and array index to pick" was not clear.

```
Func<object, object>[] funcList =
   { (value) => value,                    //0
     (value) => Convert.ToInt16(value),   //1
     (value) => Convert.ToInt32(value),   //2
     (value) => Convert.ToInt64(value),   //3
     (value) => value,   //4
     (value) => value,   //5
     (value) => value,   //6
     (value) => value,   //7
     (value) => value,   //8
     (value) => value,   //9
     (value) => value,   //10
     (value) => value,   //11
     (value) => value,   //12
     (value) => value,   //13
     (value) => value,   //14
     (value) => value,   //15
     (value) => value,   //16
     (value) => value,   //17
     (value) => value.ToString().Trim() //18
   }; 

public static object ConvertFromDBValue(Type type, object value)
{
  if (TypeDefs[type] <= 18)
    return funcList[TypeDefs[type]](value);
  else
   return value;
}
```

To make this even faster take out the `if (TypeDefs[type] <= 18)` if statement if you can guarantee there are no values greater than 18.

> This is sample non-tested code.

Comment: `TypeDefs + funcList` just to get a delegate? why not simply using a dictionary as a said in my comment? `var val = TypeDefs[typeof(short)]("12345")`

Comment: A down-vote actually, as there are two dictionary access calls ins this method....

Comment: @neggenbe - any optimizer would only make one call here.

Comment: @L.B -- Good point -- I was not looking at how the TyepDefs variable was defined I was just showing a good way to convert a swtich to an array reference.