# Improve efficiency of database row reading without boxing

Tags: c#, performance, boxing

I use a boxing approach to read data from database via a [type-switch helper class described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812177/surprisingly-bad-c-sharp-switch-performance?noredirect=1#comment68845406_40812177).

The boxing approach is mainly used for custom types that I derive from/to default types (e.g. I have a `DB_Image` element stored as an `int32` value, which correspongs to the index in a image list).

I discovered how bad this approach was in terms of performance. The question is, can I do better?

Examples welcome.

Comment: I don't understand what conversion has to happen to make an int32 into an index -- isn't an int32 an index without conversion?

Comment: Yes you are right, but if I set `DB_Image img = myTable.Row[i].Column[j]` the compilator fails... And to make things "simpler" (unfortunately not faster) I use something like `DB_Image img = TypeSwitch(typeof(DB_Image), myTable.Row[i].Column[j])` which then works...

Comment: ok but what does `TypeSwitch(typeof(DB_Image)` do?  Nothing like what you showed in the other question.

Comment: @Hogan Actually in this case I use a constructor `case DB_Image: return new DB_Image(Convert.ToInt32(value));`. This is actually done with a `TryParse` approach as the `value` might be null... Here the full point of the `TypeSwitch`...!

Comment: Everything about this just strikes me as a bad design.  You are treating columns of SQL results as generic types that you need to handle on the fly -- in fact they are not generic but strongly typed.  I'd suggest instead making a helper function optimized for the results of a given query.  Clearly the generic solution is to slow.  If you want you can only optimize the most important (time sensitive) queries this way.

Comment: @Hogan queries are ok and performance becomes a hurdle when loading 300k rows or so... Obviously, loading that many rows is inefficient, I know that. Filling the datatable is about as slow (~50% of time) and the `TypeSwitch` approach uses up about 30% of time. So it isn't THAT bad, but that's not a reason not to try to improve it...!

Comment: I'm just bringing 30 years of experience to my answer, you should ignore it if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just went to write a little test program about different approaches to read data from a `DataTable`.

I use following 4 methods to set `int`, `string`, `double` and `DateTime` properties as follows:

Set Convert:        `myObj.IntValue = Convert.ToInt32(row["int"]);`

Set cast:           `myObj.IntValue = (int)row["int"];`

Set Field:       `myObj.IntValue = row.Field<int>("int");`

Set `TypeSwitch`:       `myObj.IntValue = TypeSwitch.GetValue(typeof(int), row["int"]);`

**Test 1: data table without `DBNull` values**
Table with 10 rows, setting the 4 (`int`, `string`, `double` and `DateTime`) properties for each row, performed 1 million times:

Set Convert:        9002 ms

Set cast:           8504 ms

Set Field:       9312 ms

Set `TypeSwitch`:       10779 ms

The difference between the 3 first methods is not huge (+/-10%) but the `TypeSwitch` is paying the dictionary access price (27% slower than casting)...

**Test 2: data table with `DBNull` values**
Now, of course, there are `DBNull.Value` problems, so I need to revise methods 1 to 3, which would crash otherwise.

Table with 10 rows (5 with only non-null values, 5 with only null-values) setting the 4 (`int`, `string`, `double` and `DateTime`) properties for each row, performed 1 million times:

I therefore add a test as follows to methods 1 through 3:

`row["int"] != DBNull.Value ? xxxx : default(int)`

where `xxxx` is as in previous tests.

For `TypeSwitch`, testing for `DBNull.Value` is also done. If not null, it returns `Convert` value, otherwise it uses another switch and returns a default value as the other methods.

Here the results:

Set Convert:      16995 ms

Set cast:         16487 ms

Set Field:     17204 ms

Set `TypeSwitch`:   10652 ms

Now big surprise - we're actually **much** faster with `TypeSwitch` than the other methods... Actually, this is because we're accessing the field twice in the row in methods 1-3, so I use this revised version for methods 1&2

```
var val = row["int"];
int i = val != DBNull.Value ? xxxx : default(val);
```

Here the revised results (still 5 non-empty and 5 null rows, executed 1 million times):

Set Convert:        9256.1556 ms

Set cast:           8895.1208 ms

Set Field:       13549.9371 ms

Set `TypeSwitch`:       10935.5278 ms

Ok, we're back where we were, casting is fastest, `TypeSwitch` is now 18% slower and Field is a clear loser.

Now for the sake of completeness, let's just look at results when we remove the row field access out of the time measurements `var val = row["int"];` :

Set Convert:        630.113 ms

Set cast:           314.9697 ms

Set Field:       5149.6852 ms

Set `TypeSwitch`:       2354.9869 ms

**Kaboooom!** Clearly, what takes most of the time is actually the random access to the datable's columns, not the box conversions.

So, I went on trying to access columns by ID instead of column name (I re-added row access times to the time measurements)

Set Convert:    1480.0548 ms

Set cast:       1139.0841 ms

Set Field:   5928.8186 ms

Set `TypeSwitch`:   2923.8451 ms

Now we're at the bottom line of this test : cast is now the clear winner!

**Conclusion**
For sure, it is a bad idea to use `r.Field<int>("aId")` to set values, and `TypeSwitch` suffers the overhead of the dictionary access.

Also, it's a bad performance thing to access fields by name instead of index.

**UPDATE**

I've written another test to compare `DataTable.Fill`, `FbDataReader` and `Dapper.Query<T>` to fill a list of `ObjectA` items declared as follows :

```
public class ObjectA : ObjectBase {
        public int aID;
        public string aStr;
        public double aDbl;
        public DateTime aDate;
    }
```

I've run 20 times a sample reading the data from a Firebird 2.5 database with 322759 rows and building the corresponding `List<ObjectA>`. I added a test to check all three methods load the same number of items and that all items have matching properties.
For `DataTable` and `FbDataReader` I used the `Cast` method described above, accessing elements with their Id for `DataTable`. I realized that for `FbDataReader`, access times don't change too much whether using the field name or the column ID, I therefore kept the field name as accessor.

Here the results

```
DataTable:       42742.922 ms
FbDataReader:    31088.6197 ms
Dapper.Query<T>: 28626.5392 ms
```

So winner is clearly `Dapper`, `DataTable` is the loser, as expected. Note that times are for loading over 6Mio records, which in all three cases is pretty impressive...

Comment: The *real* performance killer is `DataTable` (especially with regards to memory) since it has a ton of overhead storing a collection of `DataColumn`s in `DataRow`s in a tree. If performance concerns you, use `DataReader` to read directly into strongly typed classes. Better yet, don't reinvent the wheel on that and use an existing ORM to do it for you. Optimizing `DataTable` access because you're concerned about boxing is like greasing the wheels of your oxcart while leaving the car in the garage.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are absolutely correct. I'd love to hear about ORM benchmarks - do you know of any?

Comment: Lots -- most performed by the ORM creators themselves and published with no implementation details and therefore quite useless. :-P My point is: even the most naive strongly typed data access is likely to have better performance than `DataTable` in almost all scenarios. Exactly which ORM would win in a shoot-out of your choosing is 1) not as important as how usable it is to you and 2) [something you should test yourself anyway](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/). My recommendation is to look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) first since it's simple and unobtrusive.

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll just check how my approach compares using a `DataReader` instead of a `DataTable` and post results when I have them!

Comment: @JeroenMostert I posted updated results promised in the pervious post. Dapper is quite impressive, thanks for the hint!!!